# Array being filled in inverse in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-state

I am trying to fill an array with several array of objects, but on first render, the values are being filled in inverse inside the array and after refreshing they go back to how they should be.

```
  const getProducts = async (data) => {
    await productServices
      .getProductsByTakeoffWizardStep(data)
      .then((response) => {
        setRows((rows) => [...rows, response.data]);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response);
      });
  };

  const getTakeoffIDs = () => {
    var i = 1;
    takeoffServices
      .getTakeoffSteps(5)
      .then((response) => {

        response.data.forEach((element) => {
          setSteps((steps) => [...steps, element.description]);
          setStepsID((stepsID) => [...stepsID, element.stepID]);
          var data = { StepID: element.stepID, TakeoffID: 4 };
          getProducts(data);
          setStepSequence((stepSequence) => [
            ...stepSequence,
            "Step " + i + "",
          ]);
          i = i + 1;
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setSteps([]);
    setStepsID([]);
    setRows([]);
    getTakeoffIDs();
  }, []);
```

So on first render the array looks like this

```
(2) [Array(1), Array(2)]
0: Array(1)
0: {product: {…}, quantity: null}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
1: Array(2)
0: {product: {…}, quantity: null}
1: {product: {…}, quantity: null}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

and after refreshing the page it looks like this

```
(2) [Array(2), Array(1)]
0: Array(2)
0: {product: {…}, quantity: null}
1: {product: {…}, quantity: null}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
1: Array(1)
0: {product: {…}, quantity: null}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

What could be causing this and what can I do to fix it?

I am accessing the page using history.push() from another page but none of the states I am passing affects the fetching process, only the display of some paragraphs not related to the data I am fetching.

Comment: can you provide more details? or the context.

Comment: @LHDi I am trying to access the page using history.push() from a table where depending on the row in the table I am fetching data. However, when I enter the page, I am receiving the data in inverse order, so the data that is supposed to be on page 1 is displaying on page 2 and vice versa. When I used console.log on the state "rows" which holds the values, I realized the values in the array were being inserted in inverse order. The response.data in the getProducts function is the array I am filling in the initial array that are dependent on the values fetched from getTakeoffIDs.

Comment: ajax requests, like most async tasks, can resolve in any random order.

Comment: @Thomas I used this method in several pages and it worked for all of them perfectly. The only difference in this page is I called a function that fetches (getProducts) from the database multiple times.

Comment: yes, you send multiple requests to the server, and they can return in any arbitrary order. Due to latency on a particular connection, some GC, some locking mechanism, or a million other reasons. The subsequent requests won't wait for the previous one to finish before responding.

Comment: Another thing I'm wondering about: why is your state so fragmented, when all these lists seem to be so tightly coupled. They don't look like you would ever update one of the states without the others. So why are they multiple separate states?

Comment: @Thomas Is there a possible solution to fix it? I need the loop since I don't know how many times I need to fetch data from the database.

Comment: @Thomas Most of the states will be removed later, these states are just added to find a final decision for the output of the steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would write this:

```
const getProduct = async (data) => {
  try {
    const response = await productServices.getProductsByTakeoffWizardStep(data);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response);
  }
}

const getTakeoffIDs = () => {
  takeoffServices
    .getTakeoffSteps(5)
    .then(async (response) => {

      // try moving setSteps(), setStepsID() and setStepSequence() up here, so they don't wait for the products.

      const products = await Promise.all(
        response.data.map(element => getProduct({
          StepID: element.stepID,
          TakeoffID: 4
        }))
      );

      setRows((rows) => [
        ...rows,
        ...products
      ]);
      setSteps((steps) => [
        ...steps,
        ...response.data.map(element => element.description)
      ]);
      setStepsID((stepsID) => [
        ...stepsID,
        ...response.data.map(element => element.stepID)
      ]);
      setStepSequence((stepSequence) => [
        ...stepSequence,
        ...response.data((_, i) => `Step ${i + 1}`)
      ]);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.response);
    });
};


useEffect(() => {
  setSteps([]);
  setStepsID([]);
  setRows([]);
  getTakeoffIDs();
}, []);
```

- Instead of calling all these `setState()`s multiple times I'd `Array.map()` the data and add it all at once.
- `await` for **all** the `getProduct()` calls to finish and also push them at once; in order.

The one thing I'm not sure about is if you want the `setRows()` to be called together with the other setter, or if the other ones should go first (because the data is available) and `setRows()` should be called later, as soon as the data is available.

Comment: The number of arrays inside rows generally depends on the number of values received from the database inside the getTakeoffSteps function. So there will be the same amount of arrays inside rows as in the other states but they aren't necessarily dependent on each other. I tried your answer and it worked. Thank You